# TextView inside of Spinner show com.jeanjn.guiadeacademia

Tags: android, textview, spinner, android-arrayadapter

I'm try to fill the spinner with a Custom ArrayAdapter. I think the spinner is filled normal, but when the application try to open it, the spinner shows com.jeanjn.guiadeacademia...., but was to be show the text I inserted in the TextView on getView(...)

Obs: I'm not speak english very well, sorry.

Obs2: I did that, with a ListView, and worked very well. Now with Spinner...

My code:

```
private void carregarSpinner() {
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.CateSpinner);
    DataBase db = new DataBase(this); 
    Cursor cursor = db.getData("SELECT * FROM Categoria");
    ArrayList<Categoria> txts = new ArrayList<Categoria>();
    while(cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        Categoria ex = new Categoria();
        ex.setNome(cursor.getString(1));
        ex.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
        txts.add(ex);
    }
    AdapterCategoria adapter = new AdapterCategoria(this, txts);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    db.closeDB(cursor);
}


public class AdapterCategoria extends ArrayAdapter<Categoria> {

    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<Categoria> itemsArrayList;

    public AdapterCategoria(Context context, ArrayList<Categoria> itemsArrayList) {

        super(context, R.id.txvCategoria, itemsArrayList);

        this.context = context;
        this.itemsArrayList = itemsArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // 1. Create inflater 
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        // 2. Get rowView from inflater
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.categoria_model, parent, false);

        // 3. Get the two text view from the rowView
        TextView labelView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txvCategoria);

        // 4. Set the text for textView 
        labelView.setText(itemsArrayList.get(position).getNome());
        labelView.setTag(itemsArrayList.get(position).getId());

        // 5. retrn rowView
        return rowView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `getDropDownView` method  in `ArrayAdapter` expects the items object to be the instance of `CharSequence` if not it will set the `item.toString()` to the `Textview`. That's why you are seeing the `class name` (com.jeanjn.guiadeacademia) in spinner drop down items

Since your item object is `Categoria` , you need to override the `getDropDownView` and provide the custom view like this,

```
@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView row = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        row.setText(getItem(position).getNome());
        return row;
}
```

Also , change your custom Adapter super constructor call as

```
super(context, R.layout.categoria_model, R.id.txvCategoria,itemsArrayList);
```

where R.layout.categoria_model is  the custom layout and R.id.txvCategoria is the textview in the layout

Comment: Thank's but not. I resolved override the method toString() in class Categoria.